# Extracting a list of all diagonals from a matrix in a specific direction

Tags: java, matrix

I'm trying to extract from a matrix all the diagonals in a certain direction, for example down-right.

For the following matrix:

```
A   B   C   D
E   F   G   H
I   L   M   N
```

the expected result should be

```
[ [A F M], [B G N], [C H], [D], [E L], [I] ]
```

A general approach is welcome.

The language I'm using is Java.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
String[] grid = {"SUGAR", 
                 "GLASS", 
                 "MOUSE"};

for( int k = 0; k < grid.length; k++ )
{   
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer( );

    for( int i = 0; i < grid.length
                && i+k < grid[0].length( ); i++ )
    {
        buffer.append( grid[i].charAt(i+k) );
    }

    trie.addWord( buffer.toString() );
}
```

output words added to the trie are

```
[ "SLU" "UAS" "GSE" ]
```

expected strings stored in the trie (order doesn't matter )

```
[ "SLU" "UAS" "GSE" "GO" "M" "AS" "R"]
```

Comment: @bhavik I have tried using all kind of for loops to do this, but so long I haven't found a way to make it work. This is part of a bigger program I have been writing and I have successfully retrieved other data from the matrix. This is the last part and I just can't figure out the pattern to apply.

Comment: Then write the code you have tried so that one can improve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an interesting problem to solve.

It's easy to get tangled up in nested loops.

I noticed if I put the words together into one string, a pattern emerged.

Taking the OP's example, the three words "SUGAR", "GLASS", "MOUSE" are concatenated together into SUGARGLASSMOUSE.

Here are the zero based character positions of the characters that I need to get from the concatenated string.  I've lined them up so you can more easily see the pattern.

```
          10     M
     5    11     GO
0    6    12     SLU
1    7    13     UAS
2    8    14     GSE
3    9           AS
4                R
```

See the pattern yet?  I have 3 indexes that consist of 5 iterations.  I have 3 words that consist of 5 letters.

The number of diagonal words is `letters + words - 1`.  We subtract 1 because the first letter in character position 0 is only used once.

Here are the results from a test I ran.

```
[ "SUGAR" "GLASS" "MOUSE" "STATE" "PUPIL" "TESTS" ]
[ "T" "PE" "SUS" "MTPT" "GOAIS" "SLUTL" "UASE" "GSE" "AS" "R" ]

[ "SUGAR" "GLASS" "MOUSE" ]
[ "M" "GO" "SLU" "UAS" "GSE" "AS" "R" ]
```

And here's the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Matrix {

    public static final int DOWN_RIGHT = 1;
    public static final int DOWN_LEFT = 2;
    public static final int UP_RIGHT = 4;
    public static final int UP_LEFT = 8;

    public String[] getMatrixDiagonal(String[] grid, int direction) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : grid) {
            builder.append(s);
        }
        String matrixString = builder.toString();

        int wordLength = grid[0].length();
        int numberOfWords = grid.length;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


        if (wordLength > 0) {
            int[] indexes = new int[numberOfWords];

            if (direction == DOWN_RIGHT) {
                indexes[0] = matrixString.length() - wordLength;
                for (int i = 1; i < numberOfWords; i++) {
                    indexes[i] = indexes[i - 1] - wordLength;
                }

                int wordCount = numberOfWords + wordLength - 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
                    builder.delete(0, builder.length());
                    for (int j = 0; (j <= i) && (j < numberOfWords); j++) {
                        if (indexes[j] < wordLength * (wordCount - i)) {
                            char c = matrixString.charAt(indexes[j]);
                            builder.append(c);
                            indexes[j]++;
                        }
                    }
                    String s = builder.reverse().toString();
                    list.add(s);
                }
            }

            if (direction == DOWN_LEFT) {
                // Exercise for original poster
            }

            if (direction == UP_RIGHT) {
                // Exercise for original poster
            }

            if (direction == UP_LEFT) {
                // Exercise for original poster
                // Same as DOWN_RIGHT with the reverse() removed
            }
        }

        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] grid1 = { "SUGAR", "GLASS", "MOUSE", "STATE", "PUPIL", "TESTS" };
        String[] grid2 = { "SUGAR", "GLASS", "MOUSE" };

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        String[] output = matrix.getMatrixDiagonal(grid1, DOWN_RIGHT);
        System.out.println(createStringLine(grid1));
        System.out.println(createStringLine(output));

        output = matrix.getMatrixDiagonal(grid2, DOWN_RIGHT);
        System.out.println(createStringLine(grid2));
        System.out.println(createStringLine(output));
    }

    private static String createStringLine(String[] values) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("[ ");

        for (String s : values) {
            builder.append("\"");
            builder.append(s);
            builder.append("\" ");
        }

        builder.append("]");

        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Super like for thinking out the box.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in table form, you could just scan the matrix up the first column, then left across the first row.

```
final String[M][N] mtx = { ... };

public List<List<String>> diagonalize() {
    final List<List<String>> diags = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int row = M - 1; row > 1; --row) {
        diags.add(getDiagonal(row, 0));
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < N; ++col) {
        diags.add(getDiagonal(0, col));
    }
    return diags;
}

private List<String> getDiagonal(int x, int y) {
    final List<String> diag = new ArrayList<>();
    while (x < M && y < N) {
        diag.add(mtx[x++][y++]);
    }
    return diag;
}
```

Comment: In your first 'for', I think you may have put ">=" instead of ">". Like this: for (int row = M - 1; row >= 1; --row)

Answer (score 2):

```
    String[] grid = {"SUGAR", 
             "GLASS", 
             "MOUSE"};
    System.out.println("Result: " + Arrays.toString(diagonals(grid)));

public static String[] diagonals(String[] grid) {
    int nrows = grid.length;
    int ncols = grid[0].length();
    int nwords = ncols + nrows - 1;
    String[] words = new String[nwords];
    int iword = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < ncols; ++col) {
        int n = Math.min(nrows, ncols - col);
        char[] word = new char[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            word[i] = grid[i].charAt(col + i);
        }
        words[iword] = new String(word);
        ++iword;
    }
    for (int row = 1; row < nrows; ++row) {
        int n = Math.min(ncols, nrows - row);
        char[] word = new char[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            word[i] = grid[row + i].charAt(i);
        }
        words[iword] = new String(word);
        ++iword;
    }
    assert iword == nwords;
    return words;
}

Result: [SLU, UAS, GSE, AS, R, GO, M]
```

First a loop with the first element on the column. Then a loop on the rows, skipping row 0.
The code in both loops is very symmetric.
Nothing too difficult. Assumed is that all strings have the same length.

As one loop:

```
public static String[] diagonals(String[] grid) {
    int nrows = grid.length;
    int ncols = grid[0].length();
    int nwords = ncols + nrows - 1;
    String[] words = new String[nwords];

    // Position of first letter in word:
    int row = 0;
    int col = ncols - 1;

    for (int iword = 0; iword < nwords; ++iword) {
        int n = Math.min(nrows - row, ncols - col);
        char[] word = new char[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            word[i] = grid[row + i].charAt(col + i);
        }
        words[iword] = new String(word);

        if (col > 0) {
            --col;
        } else {
            ++row;
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

The declaration of `word` could be brought outside the loop. Simply walks with (row, col) the left and top rim.

Comment: +1 elegant. but the method covers one side of diagonal which is from left to right. Right to left diagonal is missing which could be applied by just reversing each string

Answer (score 0):

You can represent your matrix using 2-dimensional array,

> char[][] matrix = char[][]

Then you can use for loops to iterate thorough it and extract the out put you want, input for your algorithm would be which diagonal direction you want.

For Ex; one possible input would be right down

Based on the possible inputs you have to decide on how to iterate through the loop initial conditions and terminating conditions.

start with last column first row character

> r = 0, c = coulmn_count -1;

terminating condition will be character at first_column last row index.

> r = row_count -1, c = 0;

Each iteration when reading character at last row or last column is a termination for the sub loop