# How to get all the diagonals from a matrix (2d array) in java efficiently

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I need an efficient way of getting all the diagonals from a matrix in java, for example given the following matrix:

```
System.out.println(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY-1);
        int[][] mat = { {1 , 2 , 3},
                        {6 , 7 , 8},
                        {11, 12, 13}};
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> diagonals = new ArrayList<>();
```

The array list diagonals should contain:

```
[[11], [6, 12], [1, 7, 13], [2, 8], [3], [1], [6, 2], [11, 7, 3], [12, 8], [13]]
```

Comment: Well you'll need two loops; one loop to collect all diagonals from up-left to down-right; and another to get all diagonals from up-right to down-left..

Comment: Possibly a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713327/extracting-a-list-of-all-diagonals-from-a-matrix-in-a-specific-direction